# Is it possible to accept a string array as argument in corba idl file

Tags: java

If not ,what are the other options through which one can accept a string list?

For example
when i try to compile

```
    module App{
    interface AppInterface{
       string get(in string name1,in string nameList[]);


                          };
               };
```

Here I am trying to get name1 and nameList so that I can check if that name appears in the nameList and return desired result string.

Error
Expected ')' encountered '['

PS: I've very limited  to no knowledge of Corba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sequences and Array cannot be passed directly, you need to use `typedef` first.

```
typedef sequence<string> NameList;
interface AppInterface{
   string get(in string name1, in NameList nameList);
};
```

Comment: ohk lemme try that ..ty